# Android Automotive (AOSP) - How to enable and test AP/AP, STA/STA, STA/AP concurrency features? (A12.1)

Tags: android, concurrency, wifi, android-source, automotive

I recently started to work with AOSP to build android automotive images (currently version A12.1) and i would like to know how to enable and how to use features such as

Dual access point **(AP/AP concurrency)**

Dual wifi connection **(STA/STA concurrency)**

and bridging internet access from wifi network to devices connected to the android hotspot **(STA/AP concurrency)**.

Im using imx8qm board with 88Q9098 wifi chip from NXP.

https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/wi-fi-plus-bluetooth/2-4-5-ghz-dual-band-2x2-wi-fi-6-802-11ax-plus-bluetooth-5-3-automotive-solution:88Q9098

I was told that this wifi chip should be able to support these features (with its concurrent dual wifi architecture)

I found some documentation from google about these features here:

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-ap-concurrency

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-ap-ap-concurrency

Following this it looks like we were able to make STA/AP work, because we were able to connect to wifi network with internet access and start hotspot at the same time, and the device connected to the hotspot was also able to access internet.

Trying this was fairly easy since i was just using already existing UI of android automotive => activating both sliders for hotspot and wifi (in network settings) at the same time. **But how do I test AP/AP and STA/STA features?** Im not really experienced in AOSP development, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Is there already a way to use these features but it is not by default shown in UI? or do I need some external app to do this? Or something entirely different?

And if there is someone who could explain to me or link some guide to the whole process of how features like this should be supported by vendor, I would really appreciated it :). I was unable to find any straightforward examples of what needs to be done.

Thank you for any comments. Sorry for mediocre english and sorry if the structure of the question is not what is expected here (this is my first question on stackoverflow).

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Looks like you are using an automotive build? Are you also then able to use a `user-debug` or `eng` build variant?

Comment: yes, i mostly use userdebug build, but can build any type of image (user. eng ...).